# What can r.v.s mean?

Tags: probability

I am reading "Introduction to Probability" 2nd edition (Blitzstein). He uses the abbreviation *r.v* for *random variable* which he explains. However, without introducing what "r.v.s" should mean, he uses it like this:

[image]
So what do you think this means? This is his first use of the abbreviation so I cannot provide any more info.

Comment: It is just the plural.

Comment: Oh gosh - but why in the world would you this use a punctuation mark after "r.v"?

Comment: ...because "r. vs." makes no sense.

Comment: As has already been noted, rv(s) is short for random variable(s). This notation is used in `scipy.stats` implementations of probability distributions. For example, `scipy.stats.norm.rvs(size=(10,))` samples the $N(0,\,1)$ distribution $10$ times.

Answer (score 12):

The abbreviation r.v.s is **R**andom **v**ariable**s**